# Horizontal Pod Autoscaling in Kubernetes Google Cloud with custom metric

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, horizontal-pod-autoscaling, kubernetes-hpa, horizontalpodautoscaler

I have following yaml-configuration for my horizontal pod autoscaler in GCP.

```
//...
  metrics:
    - type: Pods
      pods:
        metric:
          name: "my-custom-metric"
        target:
          type: AverageValue
          averageValue: 60

//..
```

I have added the metric as a custom metric in metric explorer in Cloud Monitoring. It is a log based metric. I have even added it to a dashboard and it looks fine.

For HPA the metric is not found. I get "Unable to read all metrics".

I'm not sure why? Do I need to add specific permissions in my serviceaccount? Or do I need to use a Custom Metrics Adapter? Does the HPA not have access without a adapter?

I have even tried to add the full name path for the metric name, but I get an error that "/" is not allowed in the name.

I would appreciate any help!

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, you need to deploy a metric server, please refer to this [link](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/metrics-server). And bear in mind that it works for cpu and memory.

1. **CPU and Memory HPA**

**Notice:**

Kubelet certificate needs to be signed by cluster Certificate Authority (**or disable certificate validation by passing --kubelet-insecure-tls to Metrics Server**)
So add under args (you will get some headaches and TLS can be added later):

```
- --kubelet-insecure-tls
```

2. **Custom metrics**

**Notice:** Before reading below check this [out](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/horizontal-pod-autoscale-walkthrough/#autoscaling-on-multiple-metrics-and-custom-metrics).

This will require some custom resource definition as well as adapter, metrics api. This video might help A LOT :)

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iodq-4srXA8&t=550s

Bonus track: do not hesitate to use siege to stress the pods, also i would try scale up and scale down :)